# Two-dimensional markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $X=(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a diffusion which solves the SDE
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \mu(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dB_t,
\end{align*}
and I have that $X$ is a Markov process.
The other process is $S_t = \max_{0 \leq r \leq t}{X_r} \lor s$ for which it is assumed that it is started at $s \geq x$ under $P^{x,s}$.
Now I want to show that $Y_t=(X_t, S_t)$ is a two-dimensional Markov process.

I tried to imitate the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256251/markov-property-for-2-dimensions-and-example) but it didn't work.